# Recursive relationship with scope

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

A user has a sponsor:

```
public function sponsor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'sponsor_id');
}
```

A user has referrals:

```
public function referrals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'sponsor_id');
}
```

A user is considered capped when they have 2 or more referrals:

```
public function activeReferrals()
{
    return $this->referrals()->whereActive(true);
}

public function isCapped()
{
    return $this->activeReferrals()->count() >= 2;
}
```

A user can give points. By default, the sponsor will receive them, but if the sponsor is capped, I want the points to go to a sponsor's referral that is NOT capped. If all the referrals are capped, then it does the same thing with the level below (the referral's referrals).

If I go user by user making database calls for each one, it's gonna take a long time. **How can I write a scope that makes recursive calls until it finds the first active referral in the tree that's not capped?**

This is what I'm trying to do:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try... I believe this will work for you :)

```
public function scopeNotCappedActiveReferrals($query, $count) {
  return $query->withCount(['referrals' => function($q) {
    $q->where('active', true);
  }])->where('referrals_count', '<', $count);
}
```

For the second part...

```
// Finally you can call it with
public function allReferrals() {
  $users = User::notCappedActiveReferrals(2)->get();

  $allUsers = $this->findNotCappedActiveReferralsRecurrsively($users);
}

// Do not place this function in the model,
// place it in your Controller or Service or Repo or blahblah...
// Also, not tested... but should work :)
protected function findNotCappedActiveReferralsRecurrsively($users) {
  if(!count($user)) {
    return $users;
  }

  foreach($users as $user) {
    $moreUsers = $user->notCappedActiveReferrals(2)->get();

    return $users->merge($this->findNotCappedActiveReferralsRecurrsively($moreUsers));
  }
}
```

Hope this is what you need :)

Comment: I'm trying to find the people that is not capped, so I changed it to `where('referrals_count', '<', $count)`. This worked fine on the first level (the sponsor's referrals). It was able to find an active user that has less than 2 active referrals.

The problem is, how would I go about checking the next level? The first one returns an empty array because there are no active users with less than 2 active referrals. How do I make this thing go all the way down but stop when it finds an eligible user?

Comment: Yes, sry for the wrong `less than/greater than` symbol. Fixed my answer. Secondly, you can simply run a recursive function to find all the users.... but. I am not sure what exactly is required here, but have a look at my edited answer... Maybe that is what you are really looking for :)

Comment: I don't want to find all the people in the entire database that is not capped. I need to find the first one that is active and not capped in the current "level". If none are found, then jump to the level below and try again, etc.. Until only 1 is returned.

Comment: What do you mean by jump to the level below? Will the next level not come only if an Active Referral is found for that particular user? How does this level system work?

Comment: The level below is shown in the image: at the top, is the sponsor. Below, the direct referrals, below the referrals of the referrals... Kinda hard to see because I didn't do a good job aligning them :P The sponsor is capped and active, so the points go to someone in the level below (his referrals). The first one that is not capped and is active will get the points. If none are found, jump to the level below (the referrals' referrals) until somone is found.

Comment: @johnRivs I believe this whole relation is too messed up for this approach. Can you explain how I am supposed to go to the next level (referrer's referral), when I am not able to find any user is the level above it (referrer)?

Comment: My bad. When I say "not find any user" I don't mean not finding any row, but not finding an eligible user. In other words, not finding a user that is not capped and active. So in the first step, the site looks at the sponsor and finds 3 referrals, but none of them are eligible for the points: the first 2 are active but capped, and the third one is, well, the one giving the points.

Comment: @johnRivs And in case when all 3 users are capped? I have to find there referrals and then look for an active but not capped user? And if found I just have to return the first of them (or all)? If not, then find active and not capped below them. Correct?

Comment: I updated the image. Yes, because the people in level 6 are not eligible (they're capped), the site checks the ones below (people in level 7). Active and not capped. Should return the first one. Ideally, it'd be able to stop after the first one to avoid extra queries. Sorry for the late response and thanks for your time.